# How to know that query come from specific row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dataTable that each row continue same class and same event.
I have this

```
<td>
   <select name="produits" onchange="loadFourAjax(this)" class="produits">
           <option value="0" selected="selected">
          <c:forEach var="i" items="${produits}">
            <option value="<c:out value="${i.id}" />">
               <c:out value="${i.designation}" />
            </option>
          </c:forEach>
    </select>
</td>
<td><select name="fournisseurs" class="fournisseurs"     
           onchange="loadRefFourAjax(this)">
    </select>
</td>
<td class="ref">
</td>
<td class="prix">
</td>
<td>   
 <input name="qte" class="qte" onkeyup="calculTotalHt(this)" type="text"/>
</td> 
<td id="total"></td>
```

My question how i can know that the query come from a current row of table, because i one to use it to select class prix and qte to calculate prix total of each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already getting the reference to the current element using `this`

That is

`loadFourAjax(this)` or `loadRefFourAjax(this)`

You can access its parent row node (`tr`) using

```
function loadFourAjax(thisObj)
{
   //other code

   var parentTr = thisObj.parentNode.parentNode;
   var prix = parentTr.querySelector(".prix").innerHTML;
}
```

use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to get the prix value

Comment: ok for exemple my event come from the input tag  i want to get the value of class "prix"

Answer (score 0):

Please move for loop from `<td>` level to `<tr>` level and append id (${i.id} from your code) to fournisseurs name.